# How to correctly pass MPI result to types

Tags: c, python-3.x, mpi, ctypes, mpich

Stackoverflowers.

I am a noob programmer.

<strike>I am working on a small project where I want to use MPI and Python without mpi4py.


For simple testing, I created a matrix multiplication running on MPI.</strike>

Let's say my output matrix is "output_mat".
When I print "output_mat" from MASTER, it shows the correct result, but when I print it from a client node, it is all zero.

In my ctypes file, it is expecting a fixed size of the output matrix.
But my MPI function has 2 "output_mat"

Now, how am I supposed to pass output_mat in MASTER to ctypes?
I do not know the minutia in the backend of MPICH.

I welcome any feedback. If you need any further information, let me know.

I don't worry about returning the output from MASTER; however, I have got another problem that is closely related to this post.

If I print the output from Python, it prints as many times as how many processes I used to run the Python program.

In my demo.py

```
    ... //some irrelevant code above

    result = mpi_matmul(mat1, 3, 3, mat2, 3, 3, output_mat, 3, 3);

    print("Expected lenght = 9, Actual length = ", len(result))
    for i in range(len(result)):
        if ((i + 1) % 3) == 0:
            print(result[i])
        else:
            print(result[i], end=" ")
```

So, if I run

```
mpirun -np 2 python3 demo.py
```

The result is

```
Expected length = 9, Actual length =  9
30.0 36.0 42.0
66.0 81.0 96.0
102.0 126.0 150.0
Expected length = 9, Actual length =  9
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Thank you for your attention in advance.

Comment: Only print on the rank of your choice.

Comment: Take a look at [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also what's with the strikeout text?

Comment: If you know how to strikeout text surely you can delete it ?  As it is it is purely distracting.  Don't thank us for our attention, make the question compelling and inviting to draw us in.